# Spring versions (End of life cycles)

Tags: spring

Where can I find specific periods of end of life of Spring Framework, for example Spring Framework v 4.1 when is its end of life or end of Support.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US VA has a release schedule that might help.
http://www.va.gov/trm/ToolPage.asp?tid=12#
You will have to click the decision tab.

Comment: I think this link no longer works. It comes up 403 for me.

Comment: There is a nother page that could be useful for you: https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#learn

Answer (score 0):

There is another (newer?) page that contains information about end of life of currently supported versions: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#supported-versions